# Concept for (almost) untraceable networking setup

Tags: vpn, proxy, tor

I have been working on an my digital footprint lately, trying to reduce it as much as possible, taking steps like fully encrypting my device with Veracrypt, installing 3 AVs, or spending hours trying to find a trustworthy VPN. However, I've realized almost every method is flawed in one way or another. So I thought, what if I combined them all?

I've found similar concepts but never an identical configuration to my own theoretical design. It should be noted this is all theoretical, and I have not actually set it up yet. My design would begin with a connection to a bullet-proof VPN, preferably hosted in Iceland, paid for with either Dash or Ethereum. From there, it would connect to a randomly selected SOCKS5 proxy, then to a commercial VPN, and finally go through TOR before connecting to the final website.

Computer > VPS > SOCKS5 > VPN > TOR

Any criticism or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What threats are you trying to protect yourself from?

Comment: nation state entities analyzing my traffic nothing illegal but i want to be at a point where even if an account of mine was to be singled out they would still be incapable of tracing my original IP.

Comment: Seems to me like this will result in your internet speed going back to the 90's, and probably will get you lots of unwanted attention from "nation state entities" for essentially no reason, assuming your claim of not doing anything illegal is genuine.

Comment: If you are protecting from government agencies than that's just the beginning of the story. You'll also have to watch your OPSEC and protect from zero-day exploits.

Comment: @MechMK1, attracting that attention might be inconvenient, but one should throw their junk mail into the same shredder as their bank statements. OP will gain little benefit from hiding from people who aren't looking for them, but people who do have reason to hide will gain a slight benefit from the increase in traffic that looks just like theirs.

Comment: There is one problem when using *uncommon* privacy protection: at least your internet provider will notice it. They will not be able to know what your are actually doing, nor whether it is legal or not. But they will see that you are trying hard to hide it. I do not think that they are actively cooperating with governmental agencies, because that would not give them more money, but I am pretty sure that if a legal action asks them which from their clients use the most hiding ways, they will give the list to the authorities...

Answer (score 2):

Using 3 AV programs at the same time is not advised. Using 2 is one too much. They will step on each other toes all the time, and maybe they won't work at all. Choose one good AV and stick to it.

Using Tor is enough. If you live on a country where using Tor is not a crime, you don't need a VPS, a VPN and a SOCKS proxy on top of that. Just Tor is enough, as your connection is not the weak link on your setup.

As others already said, you must mind your OpSec. That is the weakest link on your security, and that's the component that brings down most setups, not only on personal security, but enterprise security too. Logging into anything that could be linked to you while connected on Tor creates bits of information that can be put together and get to you. Logging on any restricted site while not on Tor can do it too.

Comment: thank you any suggestions for free AV's

Comment: If you want to really protect yourself, it is going to cost you money...

Comment: actually deleted third but malwarebytes and avast don't seem to bother one another

Answer (score 1):

> "... like fully encrypting my device with Veracrypt ..."

That's a good **security** measure to take but it has no bearing on your online digital footprint.

> "... installing 3 AVs ..."

This suggests that you are running **MS Windows**. Windows telemetry reports a huge selection of uniquely identifiable information about your computer back to MS on a regular basis. Also many AVs send unknown executables back to corporate for analysis, this *may* also include machine identifiers.

> "... a randomly selected SOCKS5 proxy, then to a commercial VPN, and
>   finally go through TOR ..."

This slows down traffic, creates needless attack surfaces, is difficult to manage, and stands out as very unusual. A *random* *Socks* *proxy* is just asking for problems. Tor was designed for anonymity and performs that function very well all by itself. Using an initial VPN before Tor is useful if there's a reason you cannot use Tor directly, but Tor is your footprint reduction.

Note that MS Windows telemetry will still happily identify you through Tor or any other TCP capable channel. Some of the virus scanners may as well. Anonymity tools like VPNs and Tor will not stop you or your software from self identifying.